# Building QGIS Master on OSX?

Tags: qgis, installation, osx

My goal is to install the latest build version of QGIS in order to test and identify bugs.  I'm on **OS X** (10.10.4) and am attempting to build from the QGIS nightly [source](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS).

I'm following the official instructions [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL).  I went to the [Github QGIS page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) and downloaded the `.zip` for the **Master** version, then installed all the requirements.  When I run `make`, I quickly get the following error:

```
[  0%] Generating qgsversion.h
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
make[2]: *** [qgsversion.h] Error 128
```

The build then progresses to 7% complete, then ends with:

```
[  7%] Built target ui
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot the above error?

I also am open to an alternative way to install and be able to test the QGIS nightly builds.  (**Note:** <del>The [qgis.dakotacarto.com](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com) nightly build appears to not be updated.</del>  As of **October 15, 2015**, [qgis.dakotacarto.com](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com) QGIS Master 2.11 appears to be updated.  See update 4 below for details.)

**Update 1:**
I cloned the repository by running the following in Terminal app:

```
clone https://github.com/qgis/QGIS.git
```

The `CMakeError.log`returns the following errors:

```
Determining if the Q_WS_X11 exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir:     /Users/mbp/Desktop/qgis_git_clone/QGIS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp  
...

Determining if the Q_WS_WIN exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir:     /Users/mbp/Desktop/qgis_git_clone/QGIS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
...

Determining if the Q_WS_QWS exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir:     /Users/mbp/Desktop/qgis_git_clone/QGIS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

**Update 2:**
Got same result when getting QGIS master via the following Terminal commands:

```
git init
git remote add -f -t master -m master qgisupstream git://github.com/qgis/QGIS.git
git merge qgisupstream
```

**Update 3:**
I updated to 10.11 El Capitan for unrelated reasons.  I thought it worth mentioning though that I got the same error as noted in **update 1**.

**Update 4:** [qgis.dakotacarto.com](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com) site has updated version QGIS Master 2.11.  I did need to update my GDAL via the Kyngchaos [GDAL Complete 1.11 framework package](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis).

Comment: For the first error you could try to clone the repository from Github instead of downloading the zip-file: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL#L1664

Answer (score 1):

As of October 15, 2015 [qgis.dakotacarto.com](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com) has the updated QGIS Master 2.11 available for download, which I'm able to download and run QGIS Master 2.11.